# Словарь в Python поиск айди

Tags: python, словарь

смотрите, у меня например есть словарь `a = {6563643: {'test': 0}}`
и мне нужно по `'test' 0` найти `6563643`

Comment: В идеале создать нужно "обратный словарь", чтобы (test, 0) было ключем для 6563643

Comment: но мне нужно найти 6563643 если в нем test это 0

Comment: Просто не используй for, в чем проблема

Answer (score 1):

Например сделайте поиск не по ключу а по значению:

```py
mydic = {6563643: {'test': 0}}

for k, v in mydic.items(): # перебираем все пары ключ:значение
    if v == {'test': 0}: # если находим искомое значение то выводим на печать.
        print(f"Значение {v} = ключу {k}")
```

P.S. Но не стоит забывать что ключи уникальны а вот значения нет.